# pwa service worker not importing scripts

Tags: php, progressive-web-apps

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/src/pwa/manifest.json"></link>
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/src/pwa/pwabuilder-sw.js');
  })};
</script>
<script src="/src/pwa/pwabuilder-sw.js"></script>
```

When i run this in a blank php file (nothing is added besides the code above) I get the error:

```
pwabuilder-sw.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined
    at pwabuilder-sw.js:3
```

How do i fix this?

my manifest:

```
{
  "dir": "ltr",
  "lang": "en",
  "name": "mysite",
  "short_name": "Home - mysite",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "browser",
  "start_url": "https://22222.net/",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "transparent",
  "description": "dsec",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "prefer_related_applications": "false",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://22222.net/22222/favicon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "2519x1504"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://22222.net/22222/favicon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "2519x1504"
    }
  ],
  "url": "https://22222.net",
  "screenshots": []
}
```

i did reg. the PWA worker, also im using the premade PWA from pwabuilder. i did add all the icon sizes (just did not add them here)

Comment: It's appears you have an error in pwabuilder-sw.js file. Can you show file content?

Comment: it's the same one from pwabuilder.com, it won't let me share the code ("too much code inn question"

Comment: If you can show at least the first 10 lines of the file code. It seems that at line 3 you have a statement that call a var importScripts that is undefined and put the error